# React.js Value not updated on button

Tags: reactjs

Console.log printing the incremented value, but value not updated in button

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { val: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    return e(
      'button',
      {
        onClick: () => {
          this.state.val = this.state.val + 1
          console.log(this.state.val)
        }
      },
      'Like' + this.state.val // here Like 1 should be displayed
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(e(Counter), domContainer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setState` to update the state. and state update is asynchronous call so you have to use call back functions to check weather store is updated or not.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { val: 0 };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
}

updateState(){
        this.setState({val : this.state.val + 1 }, function(){
            console.log(this.state.val)
        })
}

render() {
    return e(
    'button',
    {
        onClick: () => {this.updateState()
        }
    },
    'Like' + this.state.val
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should never update state directly.  Always use `setState`

```
this.state.val = this.state.val + 1;  // bad
this.setState((state) => ({           // good
    val: state.val + 1
}))
```

Otherwise React will not "see" the update and will not re-render.

Comment: I was thinking in angular way :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to update React state via `this.setState()` function. Otherwise, the component does not re-render. That's basic of React. You should read more React documents or do some tutorials.

You can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)!